# Nested list return index

Tags: python, nested-lists

In a nested list, how do you print out the 1st and 3rd index values in tuple?

```
L= [[1,2,3,4,2,3],[4,5,6,7,3,4]]
```

to return [(1,3), (4,6)]

Instead of assigning L[0][1], etc.. and returning value, returning the first index and 3rd index values in all the lists.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3,4,2,3],[4,5,6,7,3,4]]
>>> print [(l[0], l[2]) for l in L]
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and indexing

```
L= [[1,2,3,4,2,3],[4,5,6,7,3,4]]
my_output = [(value[0],value[2]) for value in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over it, using list comprehension

```
L= [[1,2,3,4,2,3],[4,5,6,7,3,4]]
my_output = [(x[0],x[2]) for x in L]
```

output:

```
[(1, 3), (4, 6)]
```